# powershell script to delete sharefolder sharing links

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive

The company that I am working for is using SharePoint to store files. People actively create sharing links to share files and folders. After a time, there are a large number of links that are not used anymore. To track these links we are using reporting tool in the Analytics tab that is called [Shared with external users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZKyr.png) (https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/siteanalytics.aspx)

This gives us a comprehensive report of sharing links inside the SharePoint site.nIn our case a number of these links are huge and we cannot delete them manually one by one.

Is it somehow possible to automate links deletion using PowerShell or any other automation tools?